useDeferredValue for non primitive values?
The react docs mentioned that:

The values you pass to useDeferredValue should either be primitive values (like strings and numbers) or objects created outside of rendering. If you create a new object during rendering and immediately pass it to useDeferredValue, it will be different on every render, causing unnecessary background re-renders.

https://react.dev/reference/react/useDeferredValue#caveats
I haven't really understood how we can use useDeferredValue for an object / arrays.
For example, if i have following variable computed by useMemo

const data = useMemo(() => ({
    alice: [..arrA],
    key2: false,
   }),[])

return <div> {JSON.stringify(data)} some large ui that i don't want to be blocking </div>


How do i implement useDeferredValue in this case?
